# How can I prevent a Lazy Spool from happening in my query?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012, query-optimization

I been struggling to optimize this query,

```
 SELECT
                dbo.OE61BLIN.Order_Key
               ,dbo.OE61BLIN.Doc_Type
               ,dbo.OE61BHED.Doc__
               ,dbo.OE61BHED.Inv_Date
               ,dbo.OE61BHED.Cust__
               ,dbo.OE61BLIN.Line_Type
               ,dbo.OE61BLIN.Item__
               ,dbo.OE61BLIN.Description
               ,(CASE
                    WHEN dbo.OE61BLIN.Doc_Type = 'I' THEN dbo.OE61BLIN.Qty_Shipped * dbo.OE61BLIN.Unit_Factor
                    WHEN dbo.OE61BLIN.Doc_Type = 'C' AND
                        dbo.OE61BLIN.return_to_inventory_ = 1 THEN -dbo.OE61BLIN.Qty_Shipped * dbo.OE61BLIN.Unit_Factor
                    ELSE 0
                END) AS QTY
               ,(CASE
                    WHEN dbo.OE61BLIN.Doc_Type = 'I' THEN dbo.OE61BLIN.Ext_Price
                    WHEN dbo.OE61BLIN.Doc_Type = 'C' THEN -dbo.OE61BLIN.Ext_Price
                    ELSE 0
                END) * (CASE
                    WHEN ISNULL(dbo.OE61BHED.Inv_Disc__, 0) <> 0 THEN 1 - (dbo.OE61BHED.Inv_Disc__ / 100)
                    ELSE 1
                END)
                AS amount
               ,dbo.OE61BHED.Inv_Disc__
               ,dbo.OE61BLIN.ITEM_GROUP
               ,dbo.OE61BLIN.Category
               ,ISNULL(dbo.AR61ACST.intercompany, 0) AS intercompany 
            FROM dbo.OE61BHED
                LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.AR61ACST
                    ON dbo.OE61BHED.Cust__ = dbo.AR61ACST.Cust__
                RIGHT OUTER JOIN dbo.OE61BLIN
                    ON dbo.OE61BHED.Order_Key = dbo.OE61BLIN.Order_Key
            WHERE (dbo.OE61BLIN.Line_Type = 'R')
            AND isnull(intercompany,0)  != 1
            AND (dbo.OE61BLIN.Doc_Type = 'C'
            OR dbo.OE61BLIN.Doc_Type = 'I')
```

Complete estimated execution plan is here 
https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=S1htt0rxN

Actual Exectuion Plan 
https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=BymztxLgE

I use SQL Sentry Plan Explorer to optimaze it ,
and it suggested that I should add the following two indexes, which I have
But it doesnt improve much, It only removed RID Look Up from plan.

```
 CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [XI_LineTypeDocType_OE61BLIN_12172018]
    ON [dbo].[OE61BLIN] ([Line_Type],[Doc_Type])
    INCLUDE ([Order_Key],[Item__],[Description],[Category],[Return_to_Inventory_],[Unit_Factor],[Qty_Shipped],[Ext_Price],[ITEM_GROUP])

    CREATE INDEX [XI_CustIntercompany_AR67ACST_12172018] ON [GarbageMark].[dbo].[AR61ACST]
    ([Cust__] ASC)
    INCLUDE ([Intercompany])
```

I am completely stuck on how to aproach this problem.

I see that Lazy Spool is the most expensive operation but I dont know how to remove 
or substitute.

Comment: It's very hard to say what the problem is with just a plan and no real knowledge of the database. I'd also challenge that the problem is the lazy spool. One thing to keep in mind is that the plan (even an actual plan) is based off of what the optimizer knows at the time you issue the statement. If it thinks it'll grab 7 rows but actually grabs 100,000, it's % would still reflect the fact that it thinks it'll bring back 7 rows. One quick sanity check is to run SET STATISTICS IO ON and then run the query. Go to messages and then check the total reads and see if one is out of whack.

Comment: Could it be the issue the way I have my joins written?
Also, all these tables have a good amount of data, each one is over 200k+ rows

Comment: If I had to throw out a guess, I would guess that OE61BLIN is returning more rows than expected which makes the nested loop join very inefficient. If you could generate the actual query plan and could share the actual / estimated numbers of the operators that would be very helpful

Comment: awesome, I will do that now. Thank you .

Comment: @MikeM. I have added an actual execution plan

Comment: It looks like everything is coming out as the optimizer expected, so I wouldn't say the operator itself is the problem. The only real way to avoid it that I could see would be force another join, which I wouldn't recommend, but if you wanted to toy with it you could find those [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/hints-transact-sql-join?view=sql-server-2017). Sorry I couldn't be of more help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regrettably you don't prefix `intercompany` in the where clause with its table name so to some extent I'm guessing that the changes you see below. I am going to suggest that you re-arrange your query to avoid the use of right outer join and then, perhaps more importantly, place the `intercompany <> 1` condition directly into the left join which 
removes the use of `ISNULL()` from your where clause.

```
SELECT
    dbo.OE61BLIN.Order_Key
  , dbo.OE61BLIN.Doc_Type
  , dbo.OE61BHED.Doc__
  , dbo.OE61BHED.Inv_Date
  , dbo.OE61BHED.Cust__
  , dbo.OE61BLIN.Line_Type
  , dbo.OE61BLIN.Item__
  , dbo.OE61BLIN.Description
  , (CASE
        WHEN dbo.OE61BLIN.Doc_Type = 'I' THEN dbo.OE61BLIN.Qty_Shipped * dbo.OE61BLIN.Unit_Factor
        WHEN dbo.OE61BLIN.Doc_Type = 'C' AND
            dbo.OE61BLIN.return_to_inventory_ = 1 THEN -dbo.OE61BLIN.Qty_Shipped * dbo.OE61BLIN.Unit_Factor
        ELSE 0
    END)                                   AS QTY
  , (CASE
        WHEN dbo.OE61BLIN.Doc_Type = 'I' THEN dbo.OE61BLIN.Ext_Price
        WHEN dbo.OE61BLIN.Doc_Type = 'C' THEN -dbo.OE61BLIN.Ext_Price
        ELSE 0
    END) * (CASE
        WHEN ISNULL( dbo.OE61BHED.Inv_Disc__, 0 ) <> 0 THEN 1 - (dbo.OE61BHED.Inv_Disc__ / 100)
        ELSE 1
    END)                                   
    AS amount
  , dbo.OE61BHED.Inv_Disc__
  , dbo.OE61BLIN.ITEM_GROUP
  , dbo.OE61BLIN.Category
  , ISNULL( dbo.AR61ACST.intercompany, 0 ) AS intercompany
FROM dbo.OE61BLIN
INNER JOIN dbo.OE61BHED  ON dbo.OE61BLIN.Order_Key = dbo.OE61BHED.Order_Key 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.AR61ACST ON dbo.OE61BHED.Cust__ = dbo.AR61ACST.Cust__ 
                            AND dbo.AR61ACST.intercompany != 1
WHERE dbo.OE61BLIN.Line_Type = 'R'
AND dbo.OE61BLIN.Doc_Type IN ('C','I')
;
```

I believe the join between OE61BLIN and OE61BHED can be an inner join, if not try using a left join.

Comment: Thank you, will try this approach today and compare the data

Comment: This worked, but I had to move the dbo.AR61ACST.intercompany != 1 to where clause because the data was a bit off when i had your way, Thanks I marked your answer as accepted.

Comment: I wasn't too certain about intercompany, but if you use it in the where clause  could form an implicit inner join (i.e. the left join may be overriden). Suggest you do NOT use isnull() as you did before, just  `AND (dbo.AR61ACST.intercompany != 1 or  dbo.AR61ACST.intercompany IS NULL)` ...  For future suggest avoiding right joins, while they are valid join types (in theory) they lead to complication in my view